# How to create a compressed dataset(images) with .p extension?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, tensorflow, training-data

I want to test traffic_sign_classification_german project with my own dataset.Here I found the train.p, test.p and train_aug.p file that was their own dataset.Now if I want to create these .p extension files what will be the procedure?please check the repo link for the project.

[repo link](https://github.com/georgesung/traffic_sign_classification_german)

Comment: Just check their code to reverse-engineer this [link](https://github.com/georgesung/traffic_sign_classification_german/blob/master/traffic_signs.py#L226). If you already did the setup, this step will cost less than 3 minutes. (Just print out type(x) and x.shape at appropriate places)

Comment: @sascha Sorry I can't understand clearly.I repeat my question again.I have some images of different signs , I want to train using these images.What will be the steps?

Comment: Their data-format is just serialized/pickled numpy-arrays or pandas dataframes. Do as i recommended to get a clear idea on type and shape and convert your images to the same, pickle them and you are ready to go.